# In VB.net Is A Line Of Code Executed As An Atomic Block

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, locking, atomic

I'm trying to learn and use more asynchronous code but have got myself confused about what is and isn't executed atomically.

```
    Private Sub PublishUpdateNotification()
        If Interlocked.Increment(WaitingThreadCount) > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Task.Run(Sub() DeliverTheNotifications())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Readonly Property WaitingThreadCount as Integer = 0
End Class
```

In the code snippet above if the method was invoked by two threads would the line `If Interlocked.Add(...` be executed as an atomic block or could a context switch happen after the first thread has incremented `WaitingThreadCount` but before it tests it's value thereby allowing the second thread to also increment the `WaitingThreadCountValue` meaning both `If` statements would test against the value of 2 and both would exit the sub which is not what I intended.

Do I need to do this test inside of a `Synclock`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking whether the increment and the comparison would be performed atomically?

Comment: @CodeAdze - The Interlocked.Increment(WaitingThreadCount) increments the specified variable and stores the result, as an atomic operation.  The test is NOT part of the atomic operation.  No number of threads can execute the Increment and return the same value.

Comment: Re your last question... you may want to prefer using a `SyncLock` over lock-free methods (like `Interlocked.Increment`) until profiling shows that the locking is a bottleneck.  You don't just need to worry about what executes atomically, you also potentially need to worry about re-ordering of memory access, especially if you expect to target processors with weaker memory ordering than the x86 family.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @dbasnett I understand that no threads can return the same value but could 1 thread preform the increment and then another thread preform the increment again before the first thread gets a chance to preform the test that `WaitThreadCount > 1`

Comment: @Craig Thanks for the info I have not heard of re-ordering of memory so will do some study on this. Another piece in the puzzel :)

Comment: Here's one link to get you started: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/

Comment: @CodeAdze - the comparison will be the value at the time of the increment for that particular thread.  There is no intervening read if that is what you are thinking.  If that is all of the code I wouldn't use any Thread locking mechanism.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for the link, the article was excellence and along with some other posts I found on Eric's blog I learnt a lot. Also, this is the second time in a row you have answered or commented on one of my questions I really appreciate the ongoing help - thanks

Answer (score 0):

FWIW

```
Private Sub PublishUpdateNotification()
    If Interlocked.Increment(WaitingThreadCount) <= 1 Then
        Task.Run(Sub() DeliverTheNotifications())
    End If
End Sub
```